# MFC - Linking Unicode code to MultiByte code

Tags: unicode, mfc

I need to integrate an old MFC code into my current VC++ application. My application is based on MFC, and is written for Unicode standard, while the old code is written for multi byte character set. Will it work if I compile the older code to a MFC DLL and link it to my Unicode project?

Comment: I would have simply tried it, but the old code does not even compile yet, and I need to determine if it is even worth spending time on fixing it.

Comment: It's really a judgement call - you'll have to determine if it's easier to do all the conversions back and forth between Unicode and multibyte, or just convert the old code to Unicode. Most of the time the compiler will help because it won't mix wide strings and multibyte strings. P.S. I'm sure you realize which option will be easier to support moving forward.

Comment: @MarkRansom, why are the conversions between unicode and multibyte needed? The Dll will export a simple function that wont have any string parameters. I was wondering if I could simply keep all my code unicode in the main application project, and retain the mutibyte code in the linked Dll, and link the two with a simple function call.

Comment: Never mind then. A more important consideration is whether you'll have one or two MFC libraries in use at the same time. See [Regular DLLs Statically Linked to MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f22wcbea.aspx) for guidance. It's been quite a while since I had to worry about this stuff.

Comment: I will liekly need more than one. Is that bad news?

Comment: No it's not, but see the article I linked for the restrictions you'll have to follow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55455/discussion-between-user2654449-and-mark-ransom).